# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::getOwnerKeyName()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, database-migration, laravel-filament

Am creating a Laravel Filament application. I have **Services** and **Offices** tables. I tried creating a **many-to-many relationship** using **office_service** table. I keep getting this error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::getOwnerKeyName()** when i use that relationship in my ServiceResource

**This is my migration**

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('office_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('office_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

**On my Service Model**

```
public function offices()
    {
return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class, 'office_service');
    }
```

**On my Office Model**

```
 public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'office_service');
    }
```

**On my filament ServiceResource this is what I have**

```
Select::make('offices')
     ->relationship('offices', 'name')
    ->preload()
     ->searchable()
   ->columnSpan(2),
```

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it in the following form to be working

[image]

[image]